# char compariison not working. how do I do this?

Tags: java

I have a statement 
 if (x[i].equals(' ')) (i'm comparing one element of a char array to  a space character to see if it is a space)
this is throwing an error.
so I googled it and found that you can't do this with a primitive.
I also found that == doesn't compare values.
so as far as I can tell from my research you can't compare the values of primitives.
is this true? if not how do you compare them?

Comment: for some reason with either of these options the if statement runs regardless of weather or not it is a space   (x[i] != 32)   { //stuff
                }
for some reason  if (x[i] != ' ')   { //stuff
                }

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used to compare the values of primitives, and the "reference values" of reference types (i.e. to see that two reference type variables are the same instance because they have the same memory address value). Use `==` for your `char` comparison, for `int` comparison, `long`, `double`, `float`, ...

You can read more about this in The Java Tutorials > [Equality, Relational, and Condition Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), and in [§ 15.21 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21), where it states:

> 15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=
>
> The value produced by the == operator is true if the value of the left-hand operand is equal to the value of the right-hand operand; otherwise, the result is false.

and

> 15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=
>
> At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is false.

Comment: if I do 
    if (x[i] = ' '')
                 
                {
it says that char cannot be converted into boolian

Comment: @namenotfound. equality uses double `=`, so you need `if (x[i] == ' '') { ...`

Comment: so   if (x[i] != ' ') shoule return true for all char which are not a space?

Comment: for some reason the code in this if statement is being ran when it is a space... and when it isn't a space...

Comment: @namenotfound. We don't have enough information to help you with that, and SO is for one query per question. Now that you know how to do equality, you should ask a new question with your new problem - you'll get a lot more help a lot faster if you do that. I would however say that I am correct, so there must be an issue with your code in another way, not due to using `==` or `!=` for `char` equality.

Answer (score 0):

== is used to compare primitives, for example a char comparison:

```
@Test
public void baz() {
    char space = ' ';
    assertTrue(space == ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chars are also numbers in Ascii-Code. A space is represented by 32 so you can test for if(x[i] == 32).

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types don't have method `equals`, try this for space character check:

```
if(32 == x[i]) {
    //its a space
}
```

OR

```
if(' ' == x[i]) {
    //its a space
}
```

OR

```
if(Character.isSpaceChar(x[i])) {
    //its a space
}
```